# Polynomial of degree 100 exist

Tags: polynomials

Find $a\in \mathbb{R}$ such that polynomial of degree 100 exist and satisfy

$P_{100}(x)-P_{100}(2014-x)=1914x+a$

Answer (score 2):

Use the relation to the expression $x-2014$

$P_{100} (2014-x)-P_{100} (2014-(2014-x))=1914(2014-x)+a$
 $P_{100} (2014-x)-P_{100} (x)=3854796-1914x+a$

So, using the first relation we have,

$3854796-1914x+a=-(1914x+a)$

$3854796=-2a$

$-1927398=a$

Comment: Nice, but how does this show that the polynomial exists?